# Matlab question: saving the path

Tags: matlab

I am working with Matlab R2011a. I want to set a path at c:\matlab (say). But it seems that the path setting is not saved and I need to reset the path every time I start Matlab. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start Matlab in a specific path, *and* have that path automatically added to your search path, you modify the `userpath` setting:

```
userpath('C:\matlab')
```

If you want to start Matlab in a specific path *without* having that path added to your search path, you have two options:

1) Create a file `startup.m` in the folder `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\toolbox\local` and write in the file `cd('C:\matlab')`. This way, whenever Matlab is started, it changes the path (you can also add other commands that should be executed upon startup).

2) Right-click onto the Matlab icon you normally use to start up the program, and in the properties, write `C:\matlab` in the `Start in` line. Thus, whenever you start Matlab from the shortcut (but not otherwise), Matlab will change path.

Comment: I am told that I do not have a privilege to save a file at C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\toolbox\local. Please advise.

Comment: @user12586: Type "userpath('C:\matlab')" in the Matlab Command Window (no double quotes), then hit the return key.

Comment: @user12586: If you don't know the administrator password to your computer, either talk to the person who has the administrator password, or try modifying the properties of the icon you click on in order to start Matlab (solution #2 of starting up in a user-defined location without adding said location to the Matlab path).

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to type  "userpath('C:\matlab')" every time I start the matlab?

Comment: I got the following: Warning: Executing startup failed in matlabrc.
This indicates a potentially serious problem in your MATLAB setup,
which should be resolved as soon as possible.  Error detected was:
MATLAB:cd:NonExistentDirectory

Comment: @user12586: Once you do the `userpath` setting, you don't need to do anything - the setting is saved (as you can check by typing `userpath`). As to your second problem: What exactly did you write into startup.m? Did you perchance save it in Rich Text Format? Anyway, once you do the userpath thing, you don't need `startup.m`, so you could delete it to fix the second issue.

Comment: @user12586: Note that from the error thrown by `matlabrc`, which is the function that calls startup, it looks like you made a typo when writing the path in the cd command - Matlab cannot change to the directory you specified because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have access to all matlab files. I had the same problem, but when I gave myself full control of the C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b folder (and all it's subfiles and folders) I no longer had this problem.

To do this, right click on the R2012b folder (or whichever version you have), and open properties.

Under the security tab, look for your username in the list. If it's not there, click "Edit..." and "Add..." your name. Then click the full control in the allow column. You may need an admin password for this.

Click "ok", "ok" (it may take a couple of minutes). Set the path again, close Matlab, reopen, and test if your setpath settings are still there.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jonas' answer (because changing the user path didn't work for me):

You can also use the start.m method "If you want to start Matlab in a specific path, *and* have that path automatically added to your search path". For Linux:

start.m

```
cd /path/to/my/folder % sets current working directory
addpath(genpath('/path/to/my/folder')) % adds directory (and its subfolders) to the path list
```

or for Window I suppose it would look like this:

start.m

```
cd c:\path\to\my\folder % sets current working directory
addpath(genpath('c:\path\to\my\folder')) % adds directory (and its subfolders) to the path list
```